# json_encode / json_decode vs Zend_Json::encode / Zend_Json::decode

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

Do you know what's the best way both for performance and memory consuming ?

Thanks in advance.

Bye.

Comment: The "best way" is to find out yourself because a benchmark makes most sense when done in a concrete application instead of some isolated environment. So grab your profiler and try.

Comment: Today the *Zend_Json* is only  a [wrapper function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function), and an **unnecessary  library overhad**. 10 years ago was also a  [conditional proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) (a workaround for old-PHP lack of json built-in functions).

Answer (score 7):

The only difference in functionality is as follows (per the Zend Framework docs):

> When a method toJson() is implemented on an object to encode, Zend_Json calls this method and expects the object to return a JSON representation of its internal state.

Other than that there are no differences and it automatically chooses to use PHP's json_encode functionality if the json extension is installed. From their docs again:

> If ext/json is not installed a Zend Framework implementation in PHP code is used for en-/decoding. This is considerably slower than using the PHP extension, but behaves exactly the same.

Comment: I feel the distinction @mylesmg makes is important. Zend_Json::encode and Zend_Json::decode **are** in fact wrappers for the native json_encode and json_decode functions, except in the situation that mylesmsg mentioned where the item that you try to encode is an object with a toJson method. If you are uncertain that the PHP version of the environment is later than 5.2.0 (this is when JSON was added to the PHP Core), using Zend_Json will be prudent. But otherwise, it would be unnecessary overhead. PS: Apologies if I'm resurrecting an old topic. Just that the question came up with my colleagues.

Comment: I agree, since 2006 Zend_Json "would be unnecessary overhead"... But must be emphatic, today, 10 years after (!), **Zend_Json is a  unnecessary overhead**.

Answer (score 5):

```
$memoryNativeStart = memory_get_peak_usage (true);
$start = microtime( true );
$native = json_decode(json_encode( $data ));
$memoryNative =  memory_get_peak_usage (true) - $memoryNativeStart;
$jsonNativeTime = microtime( true ) - $start;
$msgNative = 'Native php <br>';
$msgNative .= 'time '.$jsonNativeTime.' memory '.$memoryNative.'<br>';

echo $msgNative;

sleep(3);

$memoryZendStart = memory_get_peak_usage (true);
$start = microtime( true );
$zend = Zend_Json::decode(Zend_Json::encode( $data ));
$memoryZend =  memory_get_peak_usage (true) - $memoryZendStart;
$jsonZendTime = microtime( true ) - $start;
$msgZend = 'Zend <br>';
$msgZend .= 'time '.$jsonZendTime.' memory '.$memoryZend;

echo $msgZend;
```

inside data there is about 130,000 records (with a result set)

I get

```
Native php

time 2.24236011505 memory 158072832

Zend

time 3.50552582741 memory 109051904
```

Comment: Everybody should seriously consider to do his own performance testing here. `Zend_Json` internally uses `json_encode` and `json_decode` as well, only if you switch on `Zend_Json::$useBuiltinEncoderDecoder` you measure the real implementation's non-native performance, and this is very very bad (6 to 8x slower through our measurements here).

Comment: And just to be fair, there _are_ some rare use cases where you want to go non-native, if for example the native encoder / decoder throws over certain "non-compliant" UTF-8 inputs, like unarmored `\0`. Don't know if these are even legal, but `Zend_Json` doesn't choke upon those and happily encodes / decodes them.

Answer (score 4):

Zend_Json is there so that it can be better integrated into an OO environment.  As for performance, I would think json_encode/decode would be a bit faster, as they are built in functions (meaning they are not written in PHP).

Comment: [Zend_Json uses json_encode underneath; it's just a layer so you can use it better in an OO application.] Are you sure ? I peeped into Zend_Json_Encoder and there isn't any json_encode function so I think zend json do the job.

Comment: Interesting, they do it themselves.  Apparently I was wrong about that.  I'll revise my answer.

Comment: @Jonah I was under the same impression as you, then Aly's post made me have a look at the source and strangely enough it doesn't wrap the native function... (And i can't see any code the would ever allow it to...). Everyday is a school day!